# How to Skip only one method in Selenium

Tags: java, excel, selenium, testng

In selenium, as a part of hybrid framework using testng, the case should be skipped if 'No' is set against that test case in excel sheet.

*Note*: Test case name and the method name also same.

Here is the case:
I am using the BeforeMethod and Test annotations of TestNG. And in the excel sheet, I have  like this

> ```
> TCID          Description       Runmode
> TestCaseA1    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    N
> TestCaseA2    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    Y
> ```

As the first case is set to No, the next case also getting skipped even it is set to Yes.

Following is the code. Please provide the solution for the problem.

```
@BeforeMethod
    public void checkTestSkip(Method method) throws IOException{

        intialise();//to load the properties

         String testName = method.getName();
                if (!testUtil.isTestCaseRunnable(SuiteAXls,testName)) {
                App_Logs.info("Skipping the case as set to No");
                throw new SkipException("Skipping the case as set to No");
            }
            else {
                App_Logs.info("Not Skipping");
            }
    }

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void TestCaseA1(){
        System.out.println("test case A1");
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void TestCaseA2(){
        System.out.println("test case A11");
    }
    }



    ********************************************

    public static  boolean isTestCaseRunnable(Xls_Reader xls,String testName){
                boolean runmode=false;
        int rwcnt=xls.getRowCount("Test Cases");
        for(int j=2;j<=rwcnt;j++){
        //for(int i=0;i<method.length;i++){
            //System.out.println(method[i].getName());
            System.out.println(xls.getCellData("Test Cases","TCID",j));
            if(testName.equals(xls.getCellData("Test Cases","TCID",j))){
                if(xls.getCellData("Test Cases","Runmode",j).equals("Y")){
                    System.out.println("runmode is yes");
                    runmode=true;
                    break;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("runmode is false");
                    runmode=false;
                    break;
                }
            }   
            }

        return runmode;
    }
```

Comment: Paste the logs.  Since your default is false, I suspect it is not even going into the logical loops.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this as a TestNG function, that will not be easy -- you'll have to run your entire suite programmatically, which normally takes a lot of rewriting.

However, you *could* just use a boolean to do this, and leave TestNG out of it.

In your `if` clause that tests whether it's set to 'no', you can just set a static variable to the value of the spreadsheet cell. E.g.

```
@BeforeSuite
public static boolean runTest = true;
...
if (!spreadsheet.says.yes)
    runTest = false;
```

and now, in another class...

```
@Test
if (firstClass.runTest)
    doTheThing()
else
    System.out.println("[INFO] Skipping test...");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achievable with `IMethodInterceptor`.
Imagine you have got only 2 test methods:

```
@Listeners(SkipInterceptor.class)
public class TestMethodCandidates {

    @Test
    public void checkAddition() {
        System.out.println("I am in checkAddition!");
        assertEquals(1+2, 3, "1+2 should equal 3.");
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldBeSkipped() {
        System.out.println("I am in shouldBeSkipped!");
        assertEquals(true, true, "This anti-pattern should be skipped.");
    }
}
```

And a method interceptor:

```
public class SkipInterceptor implements IMethodInterceptor {

   /**
    * Your spreadsheet variable.
    */
    private Reader reader;

    public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> list, ITestContext iTestContext) {
        return list.stream()
                .filter(instance ->
                        !isSkippable(instance.getMethod().getMethodName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

   /**
    * In this method you can use your spreadsheet and name of the method.
    * @return true, iff this method should run.
    */
    private boolean isSkippable(String methodName) {
        if(methodName.equals("shouldBeSkipped")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

My output:

```
I am in checkAddition!
Test ignored.
```

`IMethodInterceptor` intercepts your to-be-invoked test methods, than it checks whether or not they should be skipped.
In the `isSkippable` method you can use your spreadsheet.
This can be even managed in the `intercept` method, if you prefer shorter solutions.
Let me know, if you prefer Java 7.

Answer (score -1):

You can use exclude the method in suite itself.

```
<methods>
       <exclude name="Test method name to exclude"/>
</methods>
```